# Cannot query dictionary key to get value in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Rookie python/mongo user here.

I pulled some game data from an API and stored it into MongoDB. I am trying to query the value of some of the keys to do mess around with statistics. The problem is, I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get to them.

Sample of data:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("51fe671f0b434a5ecd4c279e"),
"dire_team_id": NumberInt(350190),
"barracks_status_dire": NumberInt(3),
"match_id": NumberInt(240720294),
"barracks_status_radiant": NumberInt(63),
"cluster": NumberInt(133),
"radiant_name": "Natus Vincere",
"radiant_win": true,
"duration": NumberInt(2947),
"game_mode": NumberInt(2),
"lobby_type": NumberInt(1),
"tower_status_dire": NumberInt(1540),
"radiant_logo": NumberLong(920110421043409228),
"radiant_team_complete": NumberInt(0),
"leagueid": NumberInt(48) 
}
```

For example, I want to query the "match_id" to get its value of 240720294

I have tried this amongst other things, but cannot figure it out:
    list(db.navi.find_one({'match_id'}))

Thanks!

Comment: The docs cover this case very well: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one, so, are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Did a `find_one` get you what you wanted? If not, could you edit your question and give us an example of what you want to give and what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

```
db.navi.find_one({'match_id': 240720294})
```

That'll give you the document with the appropriate match_id. Not really clear if you're looking for other values on that document, or something else, but hopefully this can get you started...

Comment: Hey Adam - thanks! The issue I am running into is maybe more of a problem with how my data is stored... [Mongo File Link](http://db.tt/NvtXjCes)   When I run that code you gave me, I just get a list of the keys at the same dict level as "match_id", with no value. Say I wanted to get get all the dict key/value info under "Player 0", what would I do to get that?

Comment: Well, that's certainly a hefty document. But how it "ought" to be structured depends on what statistics you need to be gathering - if this is exploratory, I wouldn't worry about he data structure just yet. (Even going so far to just write JSON files, wait until you know what your use-case queries are before bringing in a database, it may well be that Mongo isn't a good fit!)

Comment: Thanks Adam. Let me clarify: the data is structured just as it comes in from the API, and just thrown into MongoDB. An example of something I'd like to do with this is: list each 'Player' along with the 'Gold' key and it's value (to make a ranking of who had the most). Maybe this is too complicated of a data set to learn off of as a beginner...

Comment: Right, so if you think about it, your players are your items of data for that query - mongo isn't a tree-database thing, it operates on documents, and in this case, the match is the document. It might support operations on nested objects (no clue, haven't used it in years) but ultimately the API it's exposing, with the data stuctures you're using, is oriented around aggregating *match* statistics. I'd still recommend using flat JSON for now, until you know what data items you'll end up working with, at that point it might be appropriate to re-write it into a separate collection.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the friendly advice.